# Reuse threads to download next segment of file

Tags: java, performance, javafx, nio, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am looking for possible methods that can increase download speed and improve cpu, memory performance. Currently I am downloading file in segments and transferring data using java nio transferFrom function.

```
public void startDownload() {
    threadService.execute(() -> {
        double currentBytes = bytesDone.doubleValue();
        //Download each segment independently.
        for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
            if (intialState[i] != -1) {
                threadService.execute(new Segment((i * sizeOfEachSegment)
                        + intialState[i], (i + 1) * sizeOfEachSegment, i));
            }
        }

        if (intialState[segments] != -1) {
            threadService.execute(new Segment((segments * sizeOfEachSegment)
                    + intialState[segments], sizeofFile, segments));
        }

        // Keep saving states of threads. And updating speed.
        while (bytesDone.get() < sizeofFile) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("thread interupted while sleeping");
                }

                System.out.println(speed
                        = (int) ((bytesDone.doubleValue() - currentBytes) / 5120));
                currentBytes = bytesDone.doubleValue();
                avgSpeed[0] += speed;
                avgSpeed[1]++;

            }
            states.saveState(stateArray, currentState);
        }
        // Download Complete.
        try {
            fileChannel.close();
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("failed to close file");
        }
        currentState.set(2);
        states.saveState(stateArray, currentState);
        System.out.println("Alhamdullilah Done :)");
        System.out.println("Average Speed : " + avgSpeed[0] / avgSpeed[1]);
    });
}

public class Segment implements Runnable {

    long start;
    long end;
    long delta;
    int name;

    public Segment(long start, long end, int name) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
            // Range header for defining which segment of file we want to receive.
            String byteRange = start + "-" + end;
            get.setHeader("Range", "bytes=" + byteRange);
            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(get)) {
                ReadableByteChannel inputChannel = Channels.newChannel(
                        response.getEntity().getContent());

                while (start < end && currentState.get() == 1) {
                    delta = fileChannel.transferFrom(inputChannel, start, 8192);
                    start += delta;
                    bytesDone.addAndGet(delta);
                    stateArray.set(name, start);
                }

                stateArray.set(name, -1);
            }
            System.out.println("Thread done: " + name);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("thread " + name + " failed to download");

        }
    }
}
```

This implementation gives 400+ kb/s but Internet Download Manager downloads same file at 500+ kb/s.
Are there any resources I can reuse(I noticed every connection initially takes time to reach its maximum speed so is there any way i can reuse the same thread to download the next portion of file as soon as it complete downloading previous)?

Comment: You could setup a connection pool as well

Comment: connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(1000);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(100);
        client = HttpClients.custom().
                setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();

Comment: client in client.execute is created using above pooling connection manager.